# Setting a variable equal to 0 or 1 using an IF statement in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

I've been searching the documentation and experimenting myself but I can't figure out whether or not you can set a variable using an IF statement. For instance

```
x = if y >= 1;
```

would set `x` equal to 1 if `y` is greater than or equal to 1 and 0 otherwise. Is this possible in SAS? Do you have to do

```
if y >= 1 then x = 1; else x = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there... just remove the `if` :

```
x = (y >= 1) ;
```

Remember, all evaluations equate to either true (1) or false (0), so you can simplify lots of code in this manner, especially with the addition of `ifn` and `ifc`.

```
x = (y >= 1) ;
z = (index(name,'Dave') > 0) ;
q = ifc(x and not z,'This','That') ;
```

Or mixing boolean & regular algebra :

```
points = ((product = 'SHOES') * 100 * sale_price) + ((product = 'HATS') * 200 * sale_price) ;
```